# JSON.stringify(dataArray) breaks for large data

Tags: asp.net, json, ajax

I have a data of 40 MB, where i have 11303 records. When i convert JSON data (JSON.stringify(dataArray)) to hidden element. It breaks with message "Not enough storage is available to complete this operation".

Here "dataArray" is of class type as below

```
public class XX_SearchResultResponse : EntityBase
 {
    public List<YY_SearchResultsList> lstSearchResults { get; set; }
    public int sessionID { get; set; }
 }

success: function (val) {

   var x = val.d;
  x = JSON.parse(x);
  val.Result = x.Result;

  if (val.Result != "") {   //val.Result is of type XX_SearchResultResponse

  var dataArray = val.Result;
  RL.Util.UnblockUI('TBL_CRR_SEARCH_RESULTS');
  RL.Util.hideProgressBar();
  document.getElementById("hidDataArrayASP").value = JSON.stringify(dataArray);
  __doPostBack(this.UniqueID, '#!@CRR');**

  }
 },
   error: function (msg) {// When Service call fails     
   RL.Util.UnblockUI('TBL_CRR_SEARCH_RESULTS');
   RL.Util.showAlertMessage('Failure' + msg, "Loading CRR data Error", 550);
   RL.Util.hideProgressBar();
   return false;
 }
```